# Changing old store to new store

Tags: database, sql-server-2008

I want to change the old store to new store by using the query in MSSQL. For example,

### Staff_Id Name Transaction_Date New_Store Old_Store

1        AA   1.1.2017         1

1        AA   1.2.2017         2

1        AA   1.3.2017         3

1        AA   1.4.2017         1

1        AA   1.5.2017         4

I want to change the table to following like that

### Staff_Id Name Transaction_Date New_Store Old_Store

1        AA   1.1.2017         1         NULL

1        AA   1.2.2017         2         1

1        AA   1.3.2017         3         2

1        AA   1.4.2017         1         3

1        AA   1.5.2017         4         1

I wrote the query like that, but it's not true, it's output randomly Update EC1 SET EC1.Old_Store=EC.New_Store
 From Employee_Change EC , Employee_Change EC1 
WHERE EC.Staff_Id=EC1.Staff_Id 
AND EC.Transaction_Date>=EC1.Transaction_Date

Comment: What have you tried so far?  What logic are you using to select a `New_Store`?

Comment: I wrote the query like that, but it's not true, it's output randomly
Update EC1
SET EC1.Old_Store=EC.New_Store
From Employee_Change EC
,  Employee_Change EC1
WHERE EC.Staff_Id=EC1.Staff_Id
AND EC.Transaction_Date>=EC1.Transaction_Date

Comment: Please don't add code to your comments, edit your question to include it.  You are also not being specific enough in your `where` clause.  You want to make sure you are only bringing back one row to `update` from, your logic there will bring back several.

Comment: How can i write to return back one row with update function?

Comment: That depends on your data.  You need to use a `where` clause that is specific enough that only one row matches the criteria.  I cannot tell you this as it is dependant on your data.

Comment: I know the result but i don't know how to retrieve the data for that. I don't know which part of the my query is wrong.

Comment: Well, think it through logically.  For example, will `where EC.Transaction_Date>=EC1.Transaction_Date` *always* return just one row?  I would imagine not.  It will return *all* rows that have a historic date.

Comment: I think it will need to write with the EXISTS condition. But I don't know the process to retrieve the data.

Comment: Why do you think that?

Answer (score 0):

```
 UPDATE EC SET Old_Store = 
(SELECT TOP 1 New_Store FROM Employee_Change As EC1 
WHERE EC1.Staff_Id = EC.Staff_Id And EC1.Transaction_Date < EC.Transaction_Date
ORDER BY EC1.Transaction_Date DESC) 
FROM Employee_Change As EC
```